# In MongoDB, how to find items basing on subcollection size?

Tags: mongodb, find, size, where-clause

Assume I have :

```
> db.users.save({name: 'John', orders:[{price: 10, date: new Date('Feb 2, 2013')}, {price: 5, date: new Date('Feb 14, 2013')}]});
> db.users.save({name: 'Tim', orders:[{price: 15, date: new Date('Jan 27, 2013')}, {price: 5, date: new Date('Feb 8, 2013')}]});
```

What would be the best practice to find "all users that have at least 2 orders in Feb 2013" ?

I assume I could use the $where operator and build a JS function that does the work but I'm afraid it would be a perf killer for my app.

I could also compute a new field for my users : Feb2013OrdersCnt that would be updated each time an order is added but I would appreciate to change the date range in my query (> 2 orders between 2013-02-01 and 2013-02-09 for example).
Is there any efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say you could use the `$size` operator ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/size/ ) but then you want a time bracketed count of array elements meaning that some of those elements will not appear for the time you are looking for.

One method could be to use the aggregation framework:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$orders'},
    {$match: {'orders.date': {$gte: new Date('01-02-2013'), $lt: new Date('01-03-2013') }}},
    {$group: {_id: '$name', sum_orders: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$match: {sum_orders: {$gte: 2}}}
])
```

That should roughly translate to: *all users that have at least 2 orders in Feb 2013*

Hope it helps,

#### Edit

For performance reasons it might be good to add a date match before the `$unwind` to omit customers that do not have orders in the range your looking for.

Comment: `match` *before* `unwind` may perform better however you have to be careful with crafting your `match` clause.  The blog post http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/12/27/mongodb-puzzlers-1/ explains the issues.

Comment: @SriSankaran Indeed mongodb matches on anything inside the array, that is the reason elemMatch was used, however the idea here is to limit the amount of root documents fed into the next pipeline so you are not unwinding unneeded documents, as such any documents whose subdocument values do not fit into the time frame should be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I'm going to check with the aggregation framework and i'll keep you posted